# WordPress permalink setup in Hindi

Tags: permalinks

I'm trying to set WordPress permalink in sitename/post name in Hindi language but it's gives me 
`%e0%a4%b2%e0%a5%8b%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%ae-%e0%a4%87%e0%a4%aa%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b8%e0%a4%ae-%e0%a4%95%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%af%e0%a4%be-%e0%a4%b9%e0%a5%88/`

This kind of permalink .

Comment: I do no see the problem here, that is most likely a correct hindi URL

Comment: I want to look permalink like "example.com/what-is-wordpress"  as same as hindi" example.com/वर्डप्रेस-क्या है" like that

Comment: Not as "example.com/%e0%a4%b2%e0%a5%8b%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%ae-%e0%a4%87%e0%a4%aa%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b8%e0%a4%ae-" like that

Comment: only a subset of ascii can be used "as is" in urls. URLs which include characters which are not ascii will be decoded in something similar to what you see. It is the responsibility of browsers (or other relevant tools) to display the urls in a more readable form

Comment: ... it might be that there is some bug with wordpress, plugin or theme, but without more context, my comments above are probably the most anyone can tell you

Comment: So what is correct way to do in because I don't what to display weird "example.com/%e0%a4%b2%e0%a5%8b%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%ae-%e0%a4%87%e0" kind of permalink

Comment: I'm using this theme https://thebootstrapthemes.com/magazine-newspaper-wordpress-theme-documentation/

Comment: I was also having the same issue here:- [gyaanhindi.com](https://gyaanhindi.com/). Now I know its because of Hindi language Unicode. Try Hind Font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the comments indicate the url is actually a correct hindi [unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls), and your browser should show it if you have the right fonts installed on your computer.

[image: as you can see, the url shows up correctly in my firefox]

as you can see in the above screenshot, the url shows up correctly on firefox

Answer (score 0):

yes when you seen in URL show in url right but when you copy and past any where then show this type codes [Rekhta...](https://rekhta.org.in/)

%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%80-%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%80-%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80/